# Linux / OS X: mv from source

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I'm just trying to get all the music from my old computer together. 
Just for fun I'm doing this from my new computer and connect to my old one via SSH. 
For the first directories I copied all .mp3 files to the same folder using 
mv *.mp3 ./oldmusic

Now I'd like to copy all files, independend of the dir, to that folder. 
Is there a possibility to make the source of mv recursively? 
(Maybe something like: mv -r *.mp3 ./oldmusic)
So that it looks for mp3 files in all directories?

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: This question is more suitable for http://superuser.com/ or http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have a look at `rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're lookin for this:

```
find src/dir/ -name '*.mp3' -exec mv {} target/dir/ \;
```